# Mount point permission change HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fuse

How can I change the ownership of a mount point (mounting is done using HDFS-FUSE)?

`chown -R user:user mount-point` doesn't work (I mean it doesn't change the ownership).

My attempt:

```
[hduser@ocs /]$ ls -ltrhd hdfs1 
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Mar 31 22:05 hdfs1

[hduser@ocs /]$ chown -R eucalyptus:eucalyptus hdfs1

[hduser@ocs /]$ ls -ltrhd hdfs1

drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Mar 31 22:05 hdfs1

[hduser@ocs /]$
```

Comment: I dont think you have right to change it. who is the owner of hdfs1 and who are you?